# Simple input/output practice

Tags: java, io

This code is just some exercise code printing questions and waiting for answers. It is working perfectly well as far as I can tell. I would like to know if this code could be considered acceptable or how it could be improved.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Citizens> list = new ArrayList<Citizens>();
        Citizens p1 = new Portuguese();
        list.add(p1);
        p1.addName();
        p1.addAge();
        p1.addAdress();
        Citizens p2 = new German();
        list.add(p2);
        p2.addName();
        p2.addAge();
        p2.addAdress();




        boolean addCitizen = true;
        while (addCitizen) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Do you want to add another citizen?Y or N?");
            String answer = input.next();
            if (answer.equals("y")) {
                System.out.println("Do you want to add a Portuguese or a German citizen?PT or GER?");
                answer = input.next();
                if (answer.equals("pt")) {
                    Citizens p3 = new Portuguese();
                    list.add(p3);
                    p3.addName();
                    p3.addAge();
                    p3.addAdress();
                } else if (answer.equals("ger")) {
                    Citizens p3 = new German();
                    list.add(p3);
                    p3.addName();
                    p3.addAge();
                    p3.addAdress();
                } else if (!answer.equals("pt") || (!answer.equals("ger"))) {
                    System.out.println("Please choose PT or GER!");
                }
            } else if (answer.equals("n")) {
                System.out.println("You´re not gonna add a new citizen!");
                addCitizen = false;

            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter y or n");
            }

        }
 System.out.println("The end"); 
 }
}
```

class Citizens

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Citizens {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String adress;
    String answer;
    public int answernr;
    boolean afirmativeanswer = true;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void addName() {

        System.out.println("Do you want to add the citizen name?Y or N?");
        answer = input.nextLine();
        while (!answer.equals("y") || (!answer.equals("n"))) {

            if (answer.equals("y")) {
                System.out.println("Please give the citizen´s name !");
                String giveName = input.nextLine();
                this.setName(giveName);
                break;
            } else if (answer.equals("n")) {
                System.out.println("Not adding a name!");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter y or n");
                answer = input.nextLine();
            }
        }

    }

    public void addAge() {

        System.out.println("Do you want to add " + this.getName() + "´s age? Y or N?");
        while (afirmativeanswer) {
            answer = input.nextLine();

            if (answer.equals("y")) {
                System.out.println("Please enter " + this.getName() + "´s age!");
                answernr = input.nextInt();
                this.setAge(answernr);
                afirmativeanswer = false;
            } else if (answer.equals("n")) {
                System.out.println("You choose not to add " + this.getName() + "´s age!");
                afirmativeanswer = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter y or n");
            }
        }
    }

     public void addAdress() {
            System.out.println("Do you want to add " + this.getName() + "´s Adress?Y or N?");

            afirmativeanswer = true;

            while (afirmativeanswer) {
              answer =  input.next();
                if (answer.equals("y")) {
                    System.out.println("Enter " + this.getName() + "´s Adress!");
                    answer = input.next();
                    this.setAdress(answer);
                    afirmativeanswer = false;
                } else if (answer.equals("n")) {
                    System.out.println("You choose not to add " + this.getName() + "´s Adress!");
                    afirmativeanswer = false;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Please choose Y or N!");

                }
            }

        }

    public void setName(String s) {
        this.name = s;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setAge(int i) {
        this.age = i;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAdress(String c) {
        this.adress = c;
    }

    public String getAdress() {
        return adress;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

The Portuguese and German classes have just one constructor each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Naming

Naming is fundamental to make your code easier to read.

```
ArrayList<Citizens> list = new ArrayList<Citizens>();
```

Name this to `citizens`.

`Citizens p1 = new Portuguese();`

`p1` is not an adequate name. Rather name it as `person1`. Replace also `p2` to `person2`.

Rename `Citizens` to `Citizen`: `person1` is `Citizen` not `Citizens`. Same thing for `person2`.

Also use correct English spelling and follow Java capitalization conventions when you name a variable:

> ```
> boolean afirmativeanswer = true;
> ```

should be `affirmativeAnswer`.

Java is a language where CamelCase is mostly respected. Why didn't you use it?

## Method

- A constructor is mostly used to access that classes methods and attributes parallel to other objects created.
- For an infinite-loop, you can do `while(true)` (preferred) or `for(;;)`. Use `break` to exit from the `while` loop. So you don't even need to use `afirmativeanswer`.
- Use `toLowerCase()` method to not differentiate from inputting `UPPERCASE` or `lowercase` characters.
- There is no need to make `answer` and `answernr` instance variables. Just put them into the methods when you need them.

Comment: Numbering variables is considered worst practice, what you're saying about constructors is nonsense and you're missing the obvious point of programming against interfaces (so declaring `list` or `citizens` as a `List<Citizen> citizens = new ArrayList<Citizen>();`

Comment: @Vogel612: 1) Numbers can be used with variables (just not at the beginning of the name), and numbered variables are not necessarily bad. 2) What I said about the constructor is relevant to its necessity.

Answer (score 4):

A few casual observations:

- Do you need that huge gap in code in your MainClass?
- You can also change your prompts, some are kind of misleading such as `System.out.println("Do you want to add another citizen?Y or N?");` which prompts for capitols, but accepts lower case y , n. Or accept lower and upper cases. Clarify all the prompts to show what kind of input Is expected.

Change these lines

```
public void addName() {

    System.out.println("Do you want to add the citizen name?Y or N?");
    answer = input.nextLine();
    while (!answer.equals("y") || (!answer.equals("n"))) {

        if (answer.equals("y")) {
            System.out.println("Please give the citizen´s name !");
            String giveName = input.nextLine();
            this.setName(giveName);
            break;
        } else if (answer.equals("n")) {
            System.out.println("Not adding a name!");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please enter y or n");
            answer = input.nextLine();
        }
    }

}
```

to this:

```
public void addName() {

do {
    System.out.println("Do you want to add the citizen name ? y or no?");
    answer = input.nextLine();
    if (answer.equals("y")) {
        System.out.println("Please give the citizen´s name !");
        String giveName = input.nextLine();
        this.setName(giveName);
        break;
    } else if (answer.equals("n")) {
        System.out.println("Not adding a name!");
        break;
    } else { //optional if you want to ask please
        System.out.println("Please enter y or n");
        answer = input.nextLine();
    }    
}
}
```

I wasn't able to double check this, and am unsure if your original while loop worked as intended. As it looks to me that it would run for any input that's not "y" or "n", so if you input "N" it would run. Which I doubt is want you wanted.

Comment: If the input isn´t  y or n in lowercase  i get the message ,Please enter y or n .My goal is to repeat thet message until i get y or n.Thanks for feedback

Answer (score 3):

## Using value objects

Instances of the `Citizen` (rightly pointed out by [@DrProgrammer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/111848/24141) that its name should be singular) class are also known as [value objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object), in which they should only contain the required values with minimal logic in it. This particular 'feature' makes them agnostic to the environment they are used in: for example, should `System.in` still be referenced if a user is using a web-based GUI?

As such, the methods `addName()`, `addAge()` and `addAddress()` are better suited in your `MainClass` (`Main`?) class, such  that they *return the desired values* for creating a `Citizen` object. Furthermore, having multiple instances of `Scanner` on a single `System.in` [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) is usually not recommended, as invoking `close()` on any of them prevents others from reading more input, and generally speaking it's not a particularly efficient way of managing an I/O resource.

## Referencing objects

It's often easier to start creating a single variable to reference an object, which in your case is `p1`. Then, you need another, so `p2` it is. Next, you have a `p3`, and it starts getting out of control have to manage `pN` variables running around your codebase. The question here is, do you need to refer to all of them at once?

Taking a step back, is it indicated to the user at any time that they are entering the details of a Portuguese citizen first, then a German one? Does this ordering matter?

A more straightforward approach to adding ***a `Citizen`*** to your `List` can be the following pseudo-code:

```
// assuming we want at least one entry, else use a while-loop to prompt first
do {
    citizenship = getCitizenship
    name = getName
    age = getAge
    address = getAddress
    if (citizenship == Portuguese) {
        list.add(new Portuguese(name, age, address));
    } else if (citizenship == German) {
        list.add(new German(name, age, address));
    }
} while (promptForNextCitizenEntry)
```

## Enumerating types

Since you are only handling for Portuguese and German citizenship, you can leverage on Java's `enum` type to define them as constants. The benefits of this approach are that you have a simpler way of validating citizenship, comparing them or even introducing new ones.

## Putting into code

`Citizen` will have a constructor that accepts the three required values:

```
public class Citizen {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String address;

    public Citizen(String name, int age, String address) {
        this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(name);
        this.age = age;
        this.address = Objects.requireNonNull(address);
    }

    // ...

}
```

You can introduce the `Citizenship` `enum`:

```
enum Citizenship {
    PT, GER;

    public static Citizenship get(String input)) {
        try {
            // toUpperCase() as the input must match the case of the values
            return Citizenship.valueOf(input.toUpperCase());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static String list() {
        return Arrays.toString(values());
    }
}
```

Your `MainClass` should look something like the following (with the aid of [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for efficient handling of I/O resources):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        // interface over implementation variable declaration,
        // and type inference for generic instance creation ('<>')
        List<Citizen> citizens = new ArrayList<>();
        do {
            Citizenship citizenship = getCitizenship(scanner);
            String name = getString(scanner);
            int age = getInteger(scanner);
            String address = getString(scanner);
            if (citizenship == Citizenship.PT) {
                citizens.add(new Portuguese(name, age, address));
            } else if (citizenship == Citizenship.GER) {
                citizens.add(new German(name, age, address));
            } else {
                // will not reach here due to the validation done above
            }
        } while (hasNextCitizen(scanner));
        // do something with citizens
    }
}

private static boolean hasNextCitizen(Scanner scanner) {
    System.out.println("Enter another citizen (true/false)? ");
    while (!scanner.hasNextBoolean()) {
        System.out.println("Please enter 'true' or 'false' without quotes.");
    }
    return scanner.nextBoolean();
}

private static String getString(Scanner scanner) {
    // similar implementation to above
}

private static int getInteger(Scanner scanner) {
    // similar implementation to above
}

private static Citizenship getCitizenship(Scanner scanner) {
    System.out.println("Enter citizenship " + Citizenship.list() + ": ");
    Citizenship result = null;
    while (!scanner.hasNext() || (result = Citizenship.get(scanner.next())) == null) {
        System.out.println("Please enter one of the following: "
                                + Citizenship.list());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback ,it´s gonna take me a while to digeste everything you said here ,it´s really heavy stuff for a beginner but it will came.